# Remove comma from unlimited items body in content type

Tags: nodes

i have a content type with multiple body fields. It's works but there is a single comma between the body fields on the rendered page. I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove that god forsaken comma. Pls help!!!

Edit, here is an image to hopefully clarify the output issue I am having:
[image]

So, the body is an array:
[image]

I need to figure where the array is being rendered so that I can remove the comma that is being used to separate the array.

Comment: Are they different body fields, or a single multi-value field? How do you render the fields? In a view?

Comment: It's a single mult value. It's being rendered by the standard node template. No views. Hth

Comment: How does the bootstrap classes get in there, and where does node-page-multi-row class originate from? You are using some support bootstrap module for that, and I bet that module is involved. On a default bootstrap themed node page those classes are not present.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else using the progressive theme:

template.php, line 458:

## from

```
  $output .= drupal_render($variables['items'][$i]) . (($i == count($variables['items']) - 1) ? '' : ', ');
```

## to

```
  $output .= drupal_render($variables['items'][$i]) . (($i == count($variables['items']) - 1) ? '' : '');
```

Comment: +1. You can shorten it even more to this: $output .= drupal_render($variables['items'][$i])

Comment: Eric, where is the difference in your suggestion? I just don't see it... from and to look the same to me...